# SQL table join with placeholder c#

Tags: c#, sql

I was wondering if anyone can help me please. I am trying populate a combobox with an sql statement. I was able to do this, then I want to populate the next combo box based on a placeholder for the first combo box, and i will have to join table together for the SQL command. I hope this makes sense. Here is my code, if anyone could suggest help, that'll be appreciated!

For the first combo box

```
private void btn_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  conn = new OleDbConnection(conString);
  string sqlcommand = @"SELECT custid, title + "" "" + firstname + "" ""+ lastname as name FROM Customer;";

  daItems = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcommand, conn);
  daItems.Fill(dtItems);

  cmbo_Customer.DataSource = dtItems;
  cmbo_Customer.DisplayMember = "name";
  cmbo_Customer.ValueMember = "custid";
  cmbo_Customer.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

now I want to populate the following combo box based on the custID place holder.

```
private void btn_ISA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    OleDbCommand dbcmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    dbcmd.CommandText = @"SELECT name FROM account INNER JOIN product ON account.prodid = product.prodid ;";

    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", cmbo_ISA.SelectedValue);

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // write exception info to log or anything else
    MessageBox.Show("Error occured!");
  }
}
```

Comment: If `CustId` only appears in the `Customers` table, then you need to include that in the join. However without knowing your schema one cannot be specific. Get the query working outside your code (use the tooling for your database).

Comment: I also tried this, would this work?  conn = new OleDbConnection(conString);
                string sqlcommand = @"SELECT name FROM account inner join product on account.prodid = product.prodid where custid = @custid;";

                daISA = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcommand, conn);
                daISA.Fill(dtISA);

                cmbo_Customer.DataSource = dtISA;
                cmbo_Customer.DisplayMember = "name";
                cmbo_Customer.ValueMember = "custid";
                cmbo_Customer.SelectedIndex = -1;

Comment: don't put code on comments please, rather edit your question. and rather test if something works, than asking if it would work? if it doesn't then you can provide more details as to why it isn't working.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is my first time using this.

Comment: The custID appears in the customer and account table. However, what I want to display in the Combo box is the name in the product table, in addition to this, if in the first combo box the user selected customer 1, in the next combo box i want it to display the name of the product theat customer owns. But i am having trouble with the joining as the custid appears in the customer and account table. Then to link to the name of the product, that is through the prodid which is found in the account and product table. Sorry, i am very confused!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, your second query:

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM account a
  INNER JOIN product p ON a.prodid = p.prodid
```

(Using aliases for the table names to make it easier to disambiguate) needs to be:

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM account a
  INNER JOIN product p ON a.prodid = p.prodid 
WHERE a.custId = @custId
```

where `@custId` is the placeholder for the parameter your adding to the `OleDbCommand`.

***BUT*** that syntax (`@name`) for the parameter in the SQL is database engine dependent (eg. SQL Server uses `@name` but Oracle uses `?` and relies on the ordering of parameters<sup>1</sup>) and you have not specified which database engine you are targetting.

<sup>1</sup> Oracle might have changed this in the more than a decade since I last used Oracle.

Comment: Apologies, but I am targeting Access Database. But I have set up the OLDECONNECTIONS etc. Thank you anyway for your help, I shall try implementing this now.

Comment: Thankfully it does not produce an error message, however the combo box is empty. I have populated the first combo box yet nothing appears in the next one.